# Cant publish to aws mqtt broker over websockets

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, websocket, mqtt, aws-iot

I am following [aws api](https://aws.github.io/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2/awsiot/mqtt_connection_builder.html#awsiot.mqtt_connection_builder.websockets_with_default_aws_signing) to connect to mqtt over websockets. Below is my code:

```
credentials_provider = AwsCredentialsProvider.new_static(
            access_key_id = auth_response_dictionary['user']['accessKeyId'],
            secret_access_key = auth_response_dictionary['user']['secretKey'],
            session_token = auth_response_dictionary['user']['sessionToken']
            )
       
    
    event_loop_group = io.EventLoopGroup(1)
    host_resolver = io.DefaultHostResolver(event_loop_group)
    client_bootstrap = io.ClientBootstrap(event_loop_group, host_resolver)    
    
    mqtt_connection = mqtt_connection_builder.websockets_with_default_aws_signing(
            endpoint=auth_response_dictionary['user']['iotEndpoint'],
            region=auth_response_dictionary['user']['region'],
            credentials_provider=credentials_provider,
            client_bootstrap=client_bootstrap,
            client_id=clientId
            )

    print("Connecting to aws")
    # Make the connect() call
    connect_future = mqtt_connection.connect()
    # Future.result() waits until a result is available
    print('connect_future ' + str(connect_future))
    x= connect_future.result()
    print('connect_future ' + str(x))
    print("Connected!")
    
    future, packet_id = mqtt_connection.publish(topic=TOPIC, payload=json.dumps(message), qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
    future, packet_id = mqtt_connection.publish(topic='test/po', payload=json.dumps(message), qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
    print('future ' + str(future))
    print('future ' + str(packet_id))
    print('Publish End')
```

I am not getting any error while connecting  and while publishing but I am not receiving any msgs on my aws mqtt broker when I subscribe to that topic there in 'Test' section.
I think that i have configured something wrong in either `credentials_provider` or `client_bootstrap` or both but dont know what.

Here are the printed logs

```
Connecting to aws
connect_future<Future at 0x7f605f942af0 state=pending>
connect_future{'session_present': False}
Connected!
future <Future at 0x7f605f8e54f0 state=pending>
future 3
Publish End
```

Can somebody please help?

Answer (score -1):

`mqtt_connection.subscribe(...)` is used to subscribe to an MQTT topic for AWS IoT messages, which I can't see anywhere in your code.

`mqtt_connection.subscribe` is called like below, taking in the topic name, a Quality of Service level and a **callback**.

```
received_count = 0
received_all_event = threading.Event()
...
topic='test/po'
print("Subscribing to topic '{}'...".format(topic))
subscribe_future, packet_id = mqtt_connection.subscribe(
        topic=topic,
        qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE,
        callback=on_message_received)
subscribe_result = subscribe_future.result()
print("Subscribed with {}".format(str(subscribe_result['qos'])))
```

`on_message_received` can look like this:

```
def on_message_received(topic, payload, dup, qos, retain, **kwargs):
    print("Received message from topic '{}': {}".format(topic, payload))
    global received_count
    received_count += 1
    # Number of messages to wait for
    if received_count = 10:
        received_all_event.set()
```

Then in your main method, you can wait until you've received 10 messages:

```
# Wait for all messages to be received.
# This waits forever if count was set to 0.
if not received_all_event.is_set():
    print("Waiting for all messages to be received...")

received_all_event.wait()
print("{} message(s) received.".format(received_count))
```

There's really good [sample code provided by AWS](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2/tree/main/samples), which I'd recommend you check out.

Comment: I have subscribed to my published topic in aws iot console in 'test' section. the problem is that i am not receiving anything there

Comment: Where? You need to subscribe to the topic - wherever `test` is, it’s not in your question